# Allow inline-block elements to wrap before stacking

Tags: html, css

I have two divs next to each other that are displayed using `inline-block`. As the viewport shrinks, I'd like the text in the leftmost div to wrap *before* the divs collapse vertically, but I can't seem to make that happen. [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kukf9kad/).

In the demo, when the viewport shrinks "Should stay in block" is pushed below the title block, whereas I'd like the "Lots of text I want to wrap" to start wrapping to keep the two blocks on the same line.

Comment: You could just [move it above](https://jsfiddle.net/6gcbenqb/).

Comment: @Jake Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear. I want them to stay beside each other. I just want the behaviour upon resize to be such that the leftmost text wraps instead of immediately plopping them on top of one another once the size is too small for the original line.

Comment: I think you'll need to use float: left rather than than use display: inline-block for this.

Comment: @DarrenS I was trying that initially but had similar issues.

Comment: @aardvarkk, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tmg6nmob/) is not the best, but appears to do what you are asking.. I would suggest using a framework like bootstrap or something similar to create a container and boxes that site next to eachother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use    `display: table-cell;`  Instead of  `display:inline-block` will solve your issue.

```css
.title { 
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: top;
}
.box {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <h2>Lots of text I want to wrap</h2>
</div>
<div class="box">
    Should stay in a block
</div>
```

Check your updated [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/kukf9kad/1/)

Comment: I think this is the closest to what I wanted to achieve because you can set a firm width for one table cell and let the other one adjust to fill as the screen gets smaller. It's a nice solution in that the HTML stays semantic -- you just treat it like a table from the CSS point of view. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you make them to fill the body or the container giving them a 50% width?
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gioele/j9dbnsxr/)
EDIT: [JSfiddle with a wrapper](https://jsfiddle.net/gioele/7t1ubvjr/)

```css
.title { 
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color:red;
    width:50%;
}
.box {
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color:blue;
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <h2>Lots of text I want to wrap</h2>
</div><div class="box">
    Should stay in a block
</div>
```

Edit: remember to not wrap after the first div, and make sure that there are not spaces `</div><div class="box">` so you can use 50% preserving the inline-block

Comment: This is very interesting. What I'm getting from this is that I need to actually SET a width on the "title" class in order for it to be resizable. That is not something I would have expected!

Comment: If you do not give a width to the div, it will be larger as much as the text is large. Same for the height!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I selected the other response as the "correct" answer because it allowed me to set a defined width for one box and let only the other one adjust. Your solution here required both boxes to be set as percentage widths which wasn't exactly what I was looking for. It's frustrating how difficult it can be to solve seemingly straightforward layout issues in HTML!